# STM32103 custom bootloader - jump to main firmware issue

Tags: assembly, stm32, bootloader

I've successfully implemented a CAN bus bootloader for the STM32103C8T6 chip based on an example I found here (lbus) https://github.com/alphalove/stm32-projects/tree/master/lbus_bootloader.

I've used libopencm3.

I've had this working very well until I made a very small change to the bootloader code.  Following that, the bootloader will no longer start the main firmware.

The bootloader starts at 0x08000000 and is 8k.
The main firmware starts at 0x08002000.

Along with other things, the booloader checks the integrity of the main firmware and if ok, starts it by calling the run_firmware() function.  This function shuts down all the chip peripherals used in the bootloader before setting the vector table address, initializing the master stack pointer, then jumping to the start of the main firmware.  Example / snippet of the run_firmware() function is the following.

```
#define FW_ADDR    0x08002000

run_firmware() {     // Set vector table base address.
   // bunch of code to reset all peripherals

   // Set Vector Table address
   SCB_VTOR = FW_ADDR & 0xFFFF;

   // Initialise master stack pointer
   __asm__ volatile("msr msp, %0"::"g"(*(volatile uint32_t *)FW_ADDR));

   // Jump to application
   (*(void (**)())(FW_ADDR + 4))();
}
```

This has been working perfectly until today when I added some additional bootloader code that also calls the run_firmware() function.  Now calling the run_firmware function does not launch the main firmware, but rather fails until the watchdog resets the chip.  While the second call to run_firmware() is in the code, the function no longer works.

Is this a limitation in jumping of an address?  Has adding the additional call changed the location of run_firmware() code in the binary that is now causing an issue?  What are the %0 and "g" in the asm doing?

To be honest, the code to start the main firmware has been black magic that I borrowed from the lbus example I linked above.  So I'm not really sure why it is failing.

If you can't tell... I'm a hardware kind of guy!

Any guidance would be most appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

alex

Comment: `SCB_VTOR = FW_ADDR & 0xFFFF;` it is wrong. It works by accident only when the FLASH is mapped to address `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use standard providerd by STM register definitions.
2. Your VTOR assignment is wrong

```
    //FW_ADDR has to be aligned to 0x100
    SCB -> VTOR = FW_ADDR;
    __set_MSP(*(volatile uint32_t *)FW_ADDR);
```

3. Jump to application start:

```
    void (*start)(void) = (void *)*(volatile uint32_t *)(FW_ADDR + 4);
    start();
```

or if you like weird expressions

```
    ((void(*)(void))(FW_ADDR + 4))();
```

Remember that your app has to be linked to match the new start point.

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void __set_MSP(uint32_t topOfMainStack)
{
  __asm volatile ("MSR msp, %0" : : "r" (topOfMainStack) : );
}
```

Comment: Hello P_J_, thanks for your response.  I'm using openlibCM3 so don't have __set_MSP available, but have implemented the same function

Comment: @Alex it is part of the ARM CMSIS and you have it available :)

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, I got locked out of editing my reply!  ;)  I've implemented a version of __set_MSP (setting sp, then __asm("msr msp, r0").  This works as expected.  I also don't have SCB->VTOR, but rather set it directly using the openlibCM3 defined memory mapped register.     Question regarding alignment of FW_ADDR.  This doesn't change and is #defined as 0x08002000.  Do I need to modify this when setting VTOR?  Yes, point taken on the CMSIS ;)

Comment: @P_J_,   Sorry, last reply was on my phone.  Just to be sure, the only thing that changes between the two bootloaders (one that successfully jumps, and one that doesn't), is an additional call to the run_firmware() function elsewhere in main().  The bootloader is less than 8k, and FW_ADDR is set to 0x08002000 for both.

Answer (score 0):

@P_J_, thanks for your help, it certainly helped me understand mechanism for jumpting to the main firmware.

That said, I found a work around rather than a proper solution to the issue (as FW_ADDR for the main firmware seem to be correctly aligned, and doesn't change between working and non-working versions of the bootloader).

I just added

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
```

to my run_firmware() function and this now works correctly from both place this is called in main().  This will do for now!

Thanks again for your time!

Cheers,

alex

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough points to comment, but just thought I'd add that there's github project (marcinbor85/can-prog) that supports bootloading via stm32's built-in (rom) bootloader.

Not sure if Alex is going to open-source his bootloader, but there's plenty of blue-pills that could benefit (including mine!)

Answer (score -2):

There is no limitation for jump address except that it must be placed at start address of a sector. To solve your problem, make sure that your boot loader code size is not more than 8 KB if so increase the size of boot loader and change the start address of main application

Comment: Hello Mostafa, thanks for the response.  The bootloader is definitely less than 8k... Basically, adding a second call to that run_furmware function has broken the jump to the main firmware... I can compile and load the bootloader which is identical except for the second call to run_firmware commented out... One will run the main firmware, one wont!  Strange!  Can only think location / ordering of the binary has changed in someway...

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The start of vector table has to be aligned to 0x100